# How do I hide an element in HTML on mobile or small windows?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I am setting up a website, and when I open it on mobile or resize the page too small, the logo at the top of the page resizes itself in a way that looks bad. It would be great if I could resize it to look good, but at this point I am running out of time and just want to make it disappear.

I have tried and failed to write JavaScript scripts to make it disappear. I can set the visibility to hidden, but I have no way to do this in a responsive way to the page getting resized and no way to detect if the webpage is too small to begin with. I have attempted to use the onresize DOM Event, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my attempt at getting HTML to use the JS function:

```
<a href="website.com" class="header_logo" id="main_logo" onresize="fixBar()">
<img src="image.png">
</a>
```

Here is the JS function (which is below all the HTML on the page) that is not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fixBar() {
  if (window.innerWidth < 400px) {
    document.getElementById("main_logo").style.visibility = "hidden";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("main_logo").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}
</script>
```

But as you can see, I still don't know how to check in the first place if the window is sufficiently small.

Also, I am working under restrictions that make it very difficult to use jQuery. If that is my only option then I will use it, but I would really prefer not to. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [CSS Media Query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) for responsiveness.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  #main_logo {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="website.com" class="header_logo" id="main_logo">
  <img src="https://placeholder.pics/svg/200x50">
  <div>Any HTML element</div>
</a>
```

Here, when the window size is less than `400px` the element with `id="main_logo"` will be removed.

Another CSS rule would be `visibility: hidden;`

There is a difference between `display: none;` and `visibility: hidden;`
Check that out [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)

Comment: You are a legend and a saint. This worked, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CSS media query to accomplish this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  #main_logo {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, if you can use CSS media query for those kind of problem.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  image-container-class {
    position: relative;
    height: 90px;
    width: 150px;
    //display: none;
  }
}
```

or if you are trying to hide logo on small devices, use display none. see the commented code at up.

Answer (score 1):

I have the almost the same situation as yours; that if the screen width is less than the my specified width it should hide the div. This is the jquery code I used that worked for me.

```
$(window).resize(function() {

  if ($(this).width() < 400) {

    $('.divIWantedToHide').hide();

  } else {

    $('.divIWantedToHide').show();

    }

});
```

You might want to combine it with a resize event with you can check you window size

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 400) {
     alert('Less than 400');
  }
 else {
    alert('More than 400');
 }
});
```

The `@media` rule is used in media queries to apply different styles for different media types/devices.

Media queries can be used to check many things, such as:

- width and height of the viewport
- width and height of the device
- orientation (is the tablet/phone in landscape or portrait mode?)
- resolution

Example :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

AND

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  #main_logo {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

checkout CSS @media Rule [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

you can go with `id` and `class` id represent it with `#` and class represent it with dot i.e `.`